# Using Rabbitmq or Hornetq for a high traffic chat component

Tags: chat, rabbitmq, hornetq

I'm working on building a high-traffic chat component for an application, and decided to build it atop a message queue, which I narrowed down to these two: Hornetq and Rabbitmq.

1. Does anyone have any opinions regarding which would be a better choice? (I plan on also coding a server that will site between the queue and users for websocket and comet tasks using java nio)
2. Can anyone point me to some good information on message throttling algorithms using these technologies?

Answer (score 2):

RabbitMQ has AMQP, if that's what you need that would be a better choice.

HornetQ is JMS centric, with support on Stomp.